# I need an alternative to the index(,match,match) function in r

Tags: r, merge, index-match

I have two datasets, `data_issuer` and `ESG_data`.

`data_issuer` contains bond pricing observations, the identity of the bond issuer is given with the `EquityISIN` variable. The same `EquityISIN` occurs multiple times in the dataset for two reasons 1. for each bond there are multiple pricing observations 2. each issuer can issue multiple bonds
The `data_issuer` dataset also contains a variable `Year`. which shows the year of the bond observation.

The first column of the `ESG_data` dataset, `ISIN CODE`, contains EquityISIN’s of public listed companies. The rest of the variables are years from 2000 til 2021. For clarity: the column names are 2000, 2001, 2002,.... 2021.

If I want to extract the ESG score of a specific company from the `ESG_data` dataset I look at the `EquityISIN` and the year, the intersection of the row and column holds the ESG score I am looking for.

I want to write a code which allows me to add a new variable to the `data_issuer` dataset called `ESGscore`. The ESG score has to be extracted from the `ESG_data` dataset using the `EquityISIN` value and the `Year` value.

I tried the following code but it returns an error:

```
merged_data <- merge(
  data_issuer, 
  ESG_data, 
  by.x = c("EquityISIN", "Year"), 
  by.y = c("ISIN CODE", "2000":"2021")
)

# Error in merge.data.frame(data_issuer, ESG_data, by.x = c("EquityISIN", : 
# 'by.x' and 'by.y' specify different numbers of columns
```

Also tried with the help of chat GPT but did not help unfortunately.

Comment: Hello Alec, please post sample data using `dput` and provide an exampe of the desired output. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805). Welcome to StackOverflow!